# Android Cursor crash

Tags: android, cursor

i've searched on web and stackoverflow but couldnt find the solution i need. In my application, i record the accelerometer coordinate values to a database, and then when user clicks on the button it writes it to a file and generate some features for this coordinate values (like standart deviation,average,max,min etc. for the given time interval) finally, it writes this features to a file too. But when i ever tried to generate these features and write it to a file, it crashed and gave that out.

```
Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetDouble(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getDouble(CursorWindow.java:543)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getFloat(CursorWindow.java:594)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getFloat(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:81)
    at com.example.coordinates.MainActivity.generateFeatures(MainActivity.java:259)
    at com.example.coordinates.MainActivity.dosyayaYaz(MainActivity.java:239)
    at com.example.coordinates.MainActivity.onDialogPositiveClick(MainActivity.java:668)
    at com.example.coordinates.dialogFragement$1.onClick(dialogFragement.java:54)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
```

this is where i think i get error.

```
private void generateFeatures(String label){

        boolean bitti=false;

        Cursor firstTimeHandler=db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(zaman) FROM Koordinatlar", null);
        firstTimeHandler.moveToFirst();

        float firstTime= firstTimeHandler.getFloat(firstTimeHandler.getColumnIndex("zaman"));
        float nextTime=firstTime+3000;

        Cursor lastTimeHandler=db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(zaman) FROM Koordinatlar", null);
        lastTimeHandler.moveToFirst();

        float lastTime=lastTimeHandler.getFloat(firstTimeHandler.getColumnIndex("zaman"));



        while(!bitti){

            calculateAverage(firstTime,nextTime);
            calculateStandartDev(firstTime,nextTime);
            calculateAverageAbsoluteDifferance(firstTime,nextTime);
            calculateAverageResultant(firstTime,nextTime);
            calculateMax(firstTime,nextTime);

            firstTime=nextTime;
            nextTime=nextTime+3000;

            if(nextTime>=lastTime){
                nextTime=lastTime;

                calculateAverage(firstTime,nextTime);
                calculateStandartDev(firstTime,nextTime);
                calculateAverageAbsoluteDifferance(firstTime,nextTime);
                calculateAverageResultant(firstTime,nextTime);
                calculateMax(firstTime,nextTime);

                bitti=true;

            }

        }

        dosyayaYaz2(label);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest cursor.getFloat(0) as you only have one column in your cursor and as others have stated the naming of MIN(zaman) is tricky

Answer (score 0):

Your log says whats wrong
`Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.`

Basically, it is trying to access a field that doesnt exist.
This is caused by the line here: or/and firstTime declaration.

```
 float lastTime=lastTimeHandler.getFloat(firstTimeHandler.getColumnIndex("zaman"));
```

So basically the field `zaman` doesnt exist.

But it does?

Check the case. Its **case sensitive** for some bizaree reason. 
It is likely your column is named **`Zaman`** not **`zamon`**

Why sql is case insensitive, this android api to get the column index, is not.

Comment: i've checked it, no problem on that.